# multi-thread writing to disk vs writing to memory with mutex

Tags: linux, mutex, hard-drive

I have a multi-thread code which needs to write log from different threads. In order to improve efficiency, I setup a memory block for the threads to write to it sync'ed by mutex. However I did a simple test and it seems like wriitng to hard drive is also fast. I'm using linux. not sure if wiritng to hard drive is actually faster or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a system buffer cache effect, hiding the real cost of disk ios, hence
the lack of difference between the 2 tests.

Comment: to bypass buffer cache, you can use O_DIRECT open flag if the filesystem you're on supports it.

Comment: so that means for modern hard drive with write cache, one doesn't really need to take the effort to create a sync'ed memory buffer like i did?

Comment: My answer was not about disk cache, but *system* cache. I would tend to answer yes to your last comment, depending on the amount of memory you have

Comment: sorry i'm kind of confused, is it advantages to design own sync'ed buffer? if not, i will just write to disk, since it's only log files, it's ok if it's kept in a buffer by the disk/system without real writing first.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the type of file system you're using now. For example, ext4 fs supports so-called 'lazy' writing. You can switch this option by passing to your mount options.

```
data=writeback.
```

This means that metadata for files can be written lazily after the file is written. This will not cause file system corruption, but it may cause the most recent changes to be lost in the event of a crash (so you may jump back into the past a bit). And as a result, *real* writing to disk will be postponed. And your tests might not be so correct.

Comment: thanks, does this mean if I switch on write cache for the ext4 fs, then it can be fast and there is no benefit to create a sync'ed memory buffer which takes a lot of effoer?

Comment: The POSIX file APIs specify quite clearly that there is no guarantee that your data is on the disk until you call fsync(). The problem is with applications that assumed they could ignore what the specification said just because it always seemed to work okay, on the file systems they tested with. So, at least, you may run fsync() in your tests, each time you do write to disc.